# Lodash isEqualWith how to customise it to not check the type of the Object?

Tags: typescript, lodash

when **_.isEqual** is comparing two objects with the same fields but one will have type he returns *false*.

The problem is that I want it to return *true* in this kind of situations.
I don't know how to create a function to _isEqualWith that will check that.

Example:

```
obj1 = {"a": "dd", "b":"ss", "c":""}
obj2 = MyTypeModel{"a": "dd", "b":"ss", "c":""}

_.isEqual(obj1, obj2);
```

will return *false*, only because one the objects have a type. 
And I want it to return *true* in this kind of cases.

So, how to check only fields without checking the type using lodash isEqualWith()?

Side note/question:

An example is simplified, but my objects are losing types because they are inside the object.
Is it okay to ignore the type? Or the problem is that typescript is not saving object types and I should initialize objects inside objects once again, before passing them to the isEqual function?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is that the objects be brought to a common type and compared.

```
const objA : Object = Object.assign({}, obj1);
const objB : Object = Object.assign({}, obj2);

console.log(_.isEqual(objA, objB));
```

NOTE: This approach may not work if the type exposes properties around the fields.

Comment: What about _.isEqual(Object.assign({}, {a: NaN}),Object.assign({},{a: null}))